# How to hide value in Chart JS bar

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, bar-chart

i try to hide the value inside the bars of my bar chart. The reason for that is that i placed the value on top of the bars, and the value should not be shown twice.

I tried different options to hide the value but it did not work.

In the following you can see a screenshot, i want to remove the numbers inside the bars.

[Image of the bars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EoK9.png)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Chart.js does not draw any data labels (values) itself by default. You most probably have activated (imported) a plugin such as [chartjs-plugin-datalabels](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/blob/master/README.md) that draws these values:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels"></script>
```

Simply remove the `script` tag from your code. To [disable a global plugin](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#disable-plugins) for a specific chart instance only, the plugin options must be set to `false`.

In the case of `chartjs-plugin-datalabels`, this would be done as follows:

```
options: {
  plugins: {
    datalabels: {
      display: false
    }
  },
}
```