# In Chart.js, how do I hide certain axis labels from a stacked bar chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I'm developing a dashboard that will show charts with ticket counts. I'm using [Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/) to render the charts. Here's an example:

[image: stacked bar chart screenshot]

In the above screenshot, Blocker and Critical bars don't appear as they have a value of zero. However, Chart.js still renders a zero where they *would* be. I think this may confuse end users, so I'd like to hide it (while still showing that category in the legend).

The following passage from the [bar chart documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/charts/bar/#internal-data-format) makes me think this is possible with `_custom`, but I haven't been able to get it working:

> {x, y, _custom} where _custom is an optional object defining stacked bar properties: {start, end, barStart, barEnd, min, max}. start and end are the input values. Those two are repeated in barStart (closer to origin), barEnd (further from origin), min and max.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

For reference, here are my current config options:

```
        options: {
                scales: { // make this a stacked chart
                    xAxes: [{
                        stacked: true
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        stacked: true
                    }]
                },
                legend: {
                    labels: {
                        boxWidth: 20 // how wide boxes on legend are
                    }
                },
                tooltips: { 
                    callbacks: {
                        footer: (tooltip_items, data) => { // add a total count to tooltips
                            let total = 0;
                            tooltip_items.forEach(element => total = total + parseInt(element.value));
                            return 'Total: ' + total;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63918506/2358409

Comment: @uminder Thank you for your help. I figured it out and posted the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My coworker figured it out. You just need to add this to the options array:

```
plugins: {
   datalabels: {
      display: function(context) {
         return context.dataset.data[context.dataIndex] > 0; // only return if greater than zero
      }
   }
}
```

Here's how it ends up looking:

[image]