# How can I hide point label in chart Js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, radar-chart

I have written below code to generate a radar chart, I am trying to hide label point in y-axis.
**Version : 2.9.4**

```
var radarData = {
labels : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13],
datasets : [
    {
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        borderColor: "rgb(255,70,0)",
        pointBackgroundColor: "rgb(255,70,0)",
        pointBorderColor: "rgb(255,70,0)",
        pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgb(255,70,0)",
        pointHoverBorderColor: "rgb(255, 99, 132)",
        data : [2,12]
    }
]
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("radar1").getContext("2d");

var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: "radar",
    fill: true,
    data: radarData,
    options: {
        legend: {
            display: false
        },
        tooltips: {
            enabled: false
        },
    }
});
```

Output I got like below

[image]

I want to remove marked label from below image

[image]

How can I remove it ?

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63918506/2358409

Comment: @uminder I want to hide 12,10,8,6,4 this all value from y axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's call ticks, to hide

```
scale: {
    ticks: {
        display: false
    }
},
```